# error in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

what is this error ? "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
"

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I used this code in my web site and I don't use from datasource .
"if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            InstalledFontCollection Fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
            GridView1.DataSource = Fonts.Families;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        } " 
thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are binding by code, the event associated with changing a page isn't supported by default.

To support it you must code by yourself the `PageIndexChanging` event. Look that you have a parameter `GridViewPageEventArgs` that allows you to know which page was selected.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanged.aspx), and a very deep article [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/gridview/Custom-GridView-with-Paging-and-Filtering.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What type of data source did you use? If the GridView doesn't have a DataSourceControl to use for these actions then you have to create your own for paging and sorting.